# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am building a project as i am including php file into index.php,

```
<?php
session_start();

require(__DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php");

$whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
$whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler);
$whoops->register();

$url = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

//Simple Routing
if($url[1] == "") {
  //home Page
  include(__DIR__ . "/../views/home.php");
  exit();
}

?>
```

the issue is that home.php has a style-sheet linked but its not loading path is correct, as i am including home.php into index.php.
In console it showing this error 
" Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html "

i also have .htaccess file code is.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Comment: The PHP code you posted is irrelevant. A fragment of the HTML it produces could help more but it still doesn't provide enough information to help solving the problem. What is the URL of the stylesheet?

Comment: Post the code of  views/home.php  also ..

Comment: i have added a screenshot with home.php text and directory structure. What i understand the issue is that as i am including home.php into index.php its including as text/html and not as css file.

Comment: `index.php` and `home.php` are not to blame here. The problem is on the web server configuration. Did you test it on a web server? What's the address?

Comment: i have tested on my local server http://localhost:8888/ its vagrant server.